# Golang - Set syscall user context in Windows

Tags: windows, iis, go, system-calls

I am making two syscalls to the [IIS Hosted Web Core (HWC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693832(v=vs.90).aspx) `WebCoreActivate` and `WebCoreShutdown` APIs. I would like to add a user context, so when the syscalls are made in Windows, they are run underneath a specific user's context - i.e., that user's permissions.

```
type WebCore struct {
    activated bool
    Handle    syscall.Handle
    Credentials syscall.Credential
}

func New() (error, *WebCore) {
    hwebcore, err := syscall.LoadLibrary(os.ExpandEnv(`${windir}\system32\inetsrv\hwebcore.dll`))
    if err != nil {
        return err, nil
    }

    return nil, &WebCore{
        activated: false,
        Handle:    hwebcore,
    }
}

func (w *WebCore) Activate(appHostConfigPath, rootWebConfigPath, instanceName string) error {
    if !w.activated {
        webCoreActivate, err := syscall.GetProcAddress(w.Handle, "WebCoreActivate")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var nargs uintptr = 3
        _, _, exitCode := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(webCoreActivate),
            nargs,
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(appHostConfigPath))),
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(rootWebConfigPath))),
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(instanceName))))
        if exitCode != 0 {
            return fmt.Errorf("WebCoreActivate returned exit code: %d", exitCode)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Server Started for %+v\n", instanceName)
        w.activated = true
    }

    return nil
}

func (w *WebCore) Shutdown(immediate int, instanceName string) error {
    if w.activated {
        webCoreShutdown, err := syscall.GetProcAddress(w.Handle, "WebCoreShutdown")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var nargs uintptr = 1
        _, _, exitCode := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(webCoreShutdown),
            nargs, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&immediate)), 0, 0)
        if exitCode != 0 {
            return fmt.Errorf("WebCoreShutdown returned exit code: %d", exitCode)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Server Shutdown for %+v\n", instanceName)
    }

    return nil
}
```

I've been reading about the `exec.Command().SysProcAttr` structure, and how you can attach specific user credentials via the `syscall.Credentials{}` structure. However, that seems limited to executing commands via `os.exec`. If I wanted to tie a specific user's context to a native syscall in Windows, how would I do that?